# How can I work around 32feet BluetoohDevicePicker crash when pressing the back button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, 32feet

I'm currently using [32Phone.NET.Phone.Bluetooth](http://32feet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) in my project, and I've discovered a small error that I feel is out of my hands.  Simply put, when I call this:

```
BluetoothDevicePicker btPicker = new BluetoothDevicePicker(); 
PeerInformation peerInfo = await btPicker.PickDeviceAsync();
deviceName = peerInfo.HostName;
```

Which pulls up a list of paired devices, however if I press the back button instead of selecting a device it crashes my app. Was wondering if there was a workaround for this? I have posted on the 32feet site, but it looks so inactivate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well, in the worst case, you could pick up the source code from the above project and debug this for yourself (and learn the cost of depending on an inactive project)...

You don't describe the crash, but if it is a managed exception, you could put a `try {} catch {}` block around this chunk of code.